# Type mismatch. Required: NotificationCompat.Style, Found: Notification.BigPictureStyle

Tags: android, notifications, androidx

I'm using AndroidX for my app, and am attempting to display a notification with a custom BigPicture style (as [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#image-style)).

However, I cannot use `.setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle()` as the `NotificationCompat.Builder` is AndroidX, whilst the `BigPictureStyle` is core android, and seemingly incompatible. Presumably the style has to come from AndroidX, but that doesn't appear to be an import option, even if manually typing in the import.

Troublesome code:

```
    val notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setLargeIcon(image)
        .setContentTitle(apod.title)
        .setContentText(apod.desc.take(100))
        .setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(image)
            .bigLargeIcon(null as Bitmap))
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Imports:

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color
import android.media.RingtoneManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
```

Potentially relevant lines of app-level `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

And of course in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Any idea what changes can be made to allow me to display a BigPicture notification whilst using AndroidX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, as soon as you write up the question you solve it.

The solution was just to change `Notification.BigPictureStyle()` to `NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()`, as all AndroidX notification libraries are named `NotificationCompat`!

Final code:

```
    val notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setLargeIcon(image)
        .setContentTitle(apod.title)
        .setContentText(apod.desc.take(100))
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(image)
            .bigLargeIcon(null))
```